# lang html tag in multilanguage Web

Tags: html, internationalization, seo, lang

It's recommended to set the `lang` tag in html as follows:

```
<html lang="en">
```

My website is ready to serve pages in a multilanguage way (english, spanish, french, etc.), depending on the location or user settings.

How should I set this tag for a good SEO? I think if I use my internationalization settings, it will be set as the search-crawler location (and I don't know if it's the right way to do it).

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: It is the most annoying things to do, and not SEO compatible. Have a URL per language. People will search keyword in a language and they are very annoyed if they get a page in different languages (and often not 100% equal). Very often English website had much more pages, so you will redirect us from the useful Google results, into shitty pages. It is OK to have the homepage which redirect to relevant language. But keep content as one URL per language, as most (but Google) websites do. BTW: it is ok to have `lang=en`. You can specify real languages on relative (and dynamic) `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to add the following for each language

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.mysite.it" hreflang="it-it" />
```

and I think this has to be done for every page

Comment: I hope someone submits a easier solution

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

Comment: Thank you, Mina. The problem is that I don't have a different page for each language. Everything is loaded in the proper language inside the same page

Comment: You are welcome, what if you point to the same site in the href as a workaround.
I don't know if this is ok or a hack

Comment: Is it possible for you to create subdirectories or subdomains and navigate to them as a side effect of changing the language in you site, and all these subdomains returns the same page but in the correct language.

Comment: I think this is crucial as that's why Google made Angular to contain subdomains for translated versions of the site, they could have easily made it in the same place if they wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

> My website is ready to serve pages in a multilanguage way (english,
> spanish, french, etc.), depending on the location or user settings.

From this phrase of yours, you can understand that you are using PI to adapt your content. **[Google does not recommend doing this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192)**:

> Do not use IP analysis to adapt your content. IP location analysis is
> difficult and generally not reliable. Furthermore, Google may not be
> able to crawl variations of your site properly. Most, but not all,
> Google crawls originate from the US, and we do not attempt to vary the
> location to detect site variations. Use one of the explicit methods
> shown here (hreflang, alternate URLs, and explicit links).

A possible solution Google suggests in this same guide:

To geotarget your site on Google:

> Page or site level: Use locale-specific URLs for your site or page.

Comment: No, no, I'm not using IP analysis. It detects the locale of your browser and tries to use the same language (if not, in english). If you register into my Web, you can choose the language you want to use from several languages

Answer (score 0):

You can make a page multilanguage by simply adding some text of that language.
The thing is that:

```
<html lang="en">
```

makes the page that language only but if you put

```
<html>
```

like simple the people who speak (e.g: Spainsh) may need to go in Google Translate but it is now multilanguaged.

Thanks in Regards,

ErrorLane